# inline input in shell command in google colaboratory

Tags: google-colaboratory

I run following command in colaboratory notebook .

```
add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
```

At the end it outputs following:

```
Also note that with apt-get a sudo apt-get dist-upgrade is needed for initial setup & with some package upgrades
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.
```

How can I input [Enter] in cell ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media -y
```